# Integer to char* and char* to Integer conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion, rsa, crypto++

I'm using the Crypto++ library, and I created this simple class:

```
class EncoderRSA
{
    public:
        EncoderRSA();
        void keyGeneration();
        void substitutePublicKey(Integer e, Integer n);
        Integer encode(std::string plainText);
        std::string decode(Integer cypher);
    private:
        AutoSeededRandomPool prng;  // Pseudo Random Number Generator
        RSA::PublicKey publicKey;   // For encrypt plain text
        RSA::PrivateKey privateKey; // For decrypt plain text
};
```

But I have some problem: when I encoded my message using `EncoderRSA::encode(message)`, I want to convert it from `Integer` to `char*` (for send by sockets) and from `char*` to `Integer` (after receive on the other side). How can I do it?

Comment: Completely depends. _How_ do you want to encode it? By what scheme? You need to strongly define your wire protocol, and either you haven't done that or you have but didn't show it to us. I'm also struggling to see what network serialisation of integers has to do with Crypto++ or RSA...

Comment: You need to back way up. Long before you write any code, you need to define and specify the protocol that you're going to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve of this problem are next two methods:

```
Integer EncryptorRSA::stringToInteger(std::string str) {
    Integer integer(str.c_str());
    return integer;
}

std::string EncryptorRSA::integerToString(Integer integer) {
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << std::hex << integer;
    return stream.str();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Integer to char* and char* to Integer conversion

I'm going to answer the question in the title, and side step the body's question because that appear to ***encrypt***, and not ***encode***.

***`Integer` to `char*`***

Its easy to get a `char*` because the `Integer` class ([header](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/integer_8h_source.html), [implementation](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/integer_8cpp_source.html)) overloads `operator<<`.

So, you would do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include "integer.h"
...

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using CryptoPP::Integer;

// Perhaps this is received from the EncoderRSA::encode() function
Integer n = ...;

ostringstream oss;
oss << n;

// Create this temporary; otherwise, you might get yourself into trouble
string str(oss.str());
cout << "string: " << str << endl;
cout << "char*: " << str.c_str() << endl;
```

***`char*` to `Integer`***

This is just as easy because the `Integer` class has a constructor for it. From [`integer.h`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html):

```
// convert from string (requires NULL terminator)
Integer (const char *str)
```

Here's the program:

```
#include <string>

#include "integer.h"
...

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using CryptoPP::Integer;

// Read from the wire
const char data[] = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890.";

// Perhaps this is passed to the EncoderRSA::decode() function
Integer n(data, strlen(data));
```

---

If you want the `byte` array version, then...

***`Integer` to `byte*`***

```
#include <vector>

#include "integer.h"
...

using std::vector;
using CryptoPP::Integer;

// Perhaps this is received from the EncoderRSA::encode() function
Integer n = ...;
size_t sz = n.MinEncodedSize();

vector v;
v.resize(sz);

n.Encode(&v[0], v.size());
```

***`byte*` to `Integer`***

This is just as easy because the `Integer` class has a constructor for it. From [`integer.h`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html):

```
// convert from string (does NOT require NULL terminator)
Decode (const byte *input, size_t inputLen, Signedness=UNSIGNED)
```

Here's the program:

```
#include "integer.h"
...

using CryptoPP::Integer;

// Read from the wire; pretend they are binary
const char byte[] = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";

// Perhaps this is passed to the EncoderRSA::decode() function
Integer n;
n.decode(data, sizeof(data));
```

---

You can get even fancier with the encoding and decoding. For example, here's a program that HexEncodes encodes them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "integer.h"
...

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using CryptoPP::Integer;

// Perhaps this is received from the EncoderRSA::encode() function
Integer n("0xfedcba0987654321fedcba0987654321fedcba0987654321fedcba0987654321");
string encoded;

size_t req = n.MinEncodedSize();
encoded.reserve(req);

HexEncoder encoder(new StringSink(encoded));
n.Encode(encoder, req);

cout << encoded << endl;
```

It produces:

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe 
FEDCBA0987654321FEDCBA0987654321FEDCBA0987654321FEDCBA0987654321
```

And you can switch to a Base64 encoder with:

```
Base64Encoder encoder(new StringSink(encoded));
n.Encode(encoder, req);

cout << encoded << endl;
```

It produces:

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe 
/ty6CYdlQyH+3LoJh2VDIf7cugmHZUMh/ty6CYdl
```